# Angular 8: safe and clean use of ElementRef and Renderer2?

Tags: angular

(*Note: this question is a distilled use case for one of the routes I am (still) exploring, related to another questions I recently posted on StackOverflow. Apologies if I duplicate my own recent question, but I believe this particular Angular usage warrants a separate questions.*)

I've read several posts and questions/answers around "low level" DOM access in Angular and how the (apparent) need for it is an indication of something wrong in the app architecture.

I'll refer to this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjc9sn-simple-posted example. In it, I do something that I haven't found a way to do with "higher level" Angular tools, like bindings, templates, directive queries etc.

### Child component template:

(it just renders a template passed into it as @Input)

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{model: model}"></ng-container>
```

### Child component class:

The code in question is in function ngAfterViewInit():

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() model: any;
  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer2: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const markedElement = (<HTMLElement>this.el.nativeElement)
      .querySelector('.marker-class');

    this.renderer2.listen(markedElement, 'click', () => {
      this.clicked.emit(this.model);
    });
  }
}
```

I use ElementRef and querySelector to find the element - not the cleanest perhaps, but at least I don't manipulate DOM, just find the element. And I use Renderer2 to subscribe to the element's click event - again would prefer higher level Angular, but at least it's Renderer2, not Renderer (which would tight-couple the code to the browser).

### Parent template:

```
<app-child [template]="demoTemplate" [model]="model" (clicked)="onChildClick()"></app-child>

<br/>
child click counter: {{counter}}

<ng-template #demoTemplate let-model="model">
    <div class="marker-class">key1: {{model.key1}}</div>
    <div>key2: {{model.key2}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is the code in my stackblitz example clean and safe enough ?
2. Is there a cleaner way to find the element (and subscribe to its event) ?

Comment: Why do you need to pass the `demoTemplate` why not just write the HTML in the child component?

Comment: Because the child component is supposed to be reusable. Any consumer will be able to supply their own template that the child component will show. Also, every consumer, inside the template, can choose which element will be the clickable one. Btw the child component will eventually do more than just the bare bones in my example.

Comment: Okay, but if the template of child component is dynamic(changes from consumer to consumer) why is it still hardcoded in the parent? Shouldn't the HTML come from the backend or something?

Comment: The parent = the consumer of the child component. To the child component, it doesn't matter where the template comes from (yes the parent could get it from the backend). All the child knows is that there can be a ".marker-class" element in the template, and the child should find it and subscribe to its click event. The child knows how to handle the clicks.